# Cannot put background image in my webpage

Tags: html, css

I am unable to put a background image on my webpage . I think it is due to container but im unable to resolve this problem . I have included my home
page code . I have used bootstrap to design the webpage. I have tried to style
it using  html{ .... 
but it seems to not have any effect on the webpage.
My code is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>POPCORN TIME</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<style type="text/css">
html{ 
      background: url(popcorn.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }

 </style>





{% block stylesheets %}
    <!-- Bootstrap provided CSS files. -->
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css" >
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;

      }

    </style>
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock stylesheets %}

   {% block javascript %}

    <!-- Bootstrap related javascript files -->

    <script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
{% endblock javascript %}
 </head>
  <body>
  {% block header %}

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="/movies-recs">Recommendations</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                       <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                         <input type="text" name="data" style="width: 70%;" />
                         <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" size="30" style="float: right" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
             </div>

           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="GET">
                <ul class="nav">
                   <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                     <li style="background-color:#C92525;font-size:14px" class="">{{user.get_username}} </li>
                     <li class=""><a href="/signout">sign out</a></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </form>
            {% else %}
            <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="{% url 'auth' %}" method="GET">
              {% csrf_token %}
               <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                 <input type="submit" name="auth_method" value="sign up" size="30" style="float: right" />
                 <input type="submit" name="auth_method" value="sign in" size="30" style="float: right" />
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you try to open the Chrome console and highlight the `<html>` element? If you did not put anything in it, its height might be 0.

Comment: your `html` and `body` end tag is  missing

Comment: Also, in the Chrome console, please verify that you don't get a 404 for `popcorn.jpg`.

Comment: It is working for me. You might be giving wrong path for the image

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the snippet your code is working fine as it is. You might just be giving the wrong path for the image

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>POPCORN TIME</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<style type="text/css">
html{ 
      background: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }

 </style>





{% block stylesheets %}
    <!-- Bootstrap provided CSS files. -->
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css" >
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;

      }

    </style>
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock stylesheets %}

   {% block javascript %}

    <!-- Bootstrap related javascript files -->

    <script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
{% endblock javascript %}
 </head>
  <body>
  {% block header %}

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="/movies-recs">Recommendations</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                       <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                         <input type="text" name="data" style="width: 70%;" />
                         <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" size="30" style="float: right" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
             </div>

           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="GET">
                <ul class="nav">
                   <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                     <li style="background-color:#C92525;font-size:14px" class="">{{user.get_username}} </li>
                     <li class=""><a href="/signout">sign out</a></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </form>
            {% else %}
            <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="{% url 'auth' %}" method="GET">
              {% csrf_token %}
               <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                 <input type="submit" name="auth_method" value="sign up" size="30" style="float: right" />
                 <input type="submit" name="auth_method" value="sign in" size="30" style="float: right" />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be missing quotes in your code:

Try changing

```
background: url(popcorn.jpg)
```

to

```
background: url("popcorn.jpg")
```

Comment: would you mind to explain why this should fix OP issue? Code only answers are discouraged on SO

Comment: the OP probably just forgot to include quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

I would put the background styling into one of the following HTML tags instead of HTML itself.

*{
}

or

body{
}

I would also change "background: url(popcorn.jpg)" to  background-image: url("popcorn.jpg"); as you are only allocating one style to the background.